# Process Explorer doesn't show all privileges

Tags: windows-7, privileges, process-explorer

Win7 x64 Enterprise, Process Explorer v16.20.

On a process' Security tab, only a few privileges are listed instead of [three dozen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx) as it should:

[image: process properties security tab]

I doesn't matter if I run Process Explorer elevated or not.

Comment: Why do you expect it to list all privileges? I’d expect it only to list those that are explicitly enabled or disabled.

Comment: @DanielB well, a privilege can only be enabled or disabled, there's no other state, no?

Comment: But there is: Absent from the security token. Which would result in some default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [What is the State column returned by whoami /priv?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e24a35b3-fb72-4918-8e51-562e2ad8d8f5/what-is-the-state-column-returned-by-whoami-priv?forum=winserversecurity), a privilege is only present in the list if it can be acquired at all.

Kind of a Polichinelle secret: not only can't I acquire a privilege, I can't even find out that it exists :)